# Plotting a Apache DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

is there any possibility to plot an APACHE Dataframe? I figured it out while converting it to a Pandas dataframe which takes a lot of time and is not my goal.
In particular, the goal is to plot a map out of an Apache DataFrame without convertion to a Pandas DataFrame. 
With plotting I mean to use a library such as matplotlib or plotly for plotting a graph or something similar.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean plot an Spark Dataframe?

In that case, you could do something like this, having yourDF as your Dataframe:

```
yourDF.show(100, truncate=false)
```

This will show in your logging your dataframe structure and values (in this case, first 100 rows) the same way you'll find in pandas. With the truncate option you specify you want to show the whole dataframe instead of a reduced version.

**EDIT**: in order to directly plot from a dataframe, please check the [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/apache-spark/) lib, o the

```
display(dataframe)
```

function, documented [here](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/index.html#visualizations-in-python).

Comment: Of course this could have some time in order to complete the operation, due to show() also needs to collect all distributed data.

Comment: I should respecify what I want. I am currently plotting with ploty or matplotlib certain graphs out of operations within the Spark DataFrame but always need to transform to a pandas dataframe before. Is it possible to do this directly out of an Apache Spark DataFrame?

Comment: Ok! Then what you need is Plotly. I edit my answer ; )